# How do I make a FIXED <div> still be recognized by other tags?

Tags: html, css, css-position, banner

I have a `<div>` which goes across the page and its position is fixed at the top. I want it to be like a banner and the rest of the `<body>` be presented below this banner however since its position : (is) fixed, the banner covers some of the rest of the contents.

```
//This is the CSS
#banner {
height: 127px;
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
}
```

Below, in the html, you can see the `<p>` tag, this becomes covered by the banner, I know I can use margin-top to sort this out but is there a way for the tags to actually recognize the presence of the `<div>` and give way to it?

```
//This is the html, you can guess what it is...

<div id="banner"></div>

<p>Hello world</p>
```

Thanks in advance, P.S: I've tried clear: both; in CSS - still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the content a `margin-top: 127px` or `top: 127px;` property. I would also wrap the content in a div so that this is done for all of your content.

This code would fix your problem:

```
<div id="banner"></div>
<div class="wrapper"> <!-- Content Wrapper -->
    <p>Hello world</p>
</div> <!-- End Content Wrapper -->
```

CSS:

```
/* This is the CSS */

#banner {
    height: 127px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}

.wrapper {
    margin-top: 127px;
}
```

You could also do:

```
.wrapper {
    top: 127px;
}
```

I wouldn't personally recommend using `padding: 127px;` on the `body` like Paulie_D suggested, simply because this would prevent you from adding padding to your content. `margin: 127px;` how I suggested is what I would recommend as it gives you more flexibility. Although, you should use the method that you prefer, as that is the main thing and both methods do work.

PS. You mixed up your CSS comments with JS comments.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `padding-top` to the body

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  padding-top: 127px;
}
#banner {
  height: 127px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="banner"></div>

<p>Hello world</p>
```

Comment: + and yet to consider `body { overflow:auto; }`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `margin-top`, then you can place a div after your banner, with the same height and make that div push the rest down.

So your code will look like this:

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}
#banner {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
.push, #banner {
    height: 127px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="banner">
    <p>Banner!</p>
</div>
<div class="push"></div>
<div class="container">
    <p>Hello world</p>
</div>
```

I also made a JSFiddle: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/h233rzwv/)